# How to get name of particular file in a folder and assign to variable using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a Windows batch file that take the file name with particular pattern (say test*.zip ) and assign it to variable. so that I can check/validate whether the file is exists in other location or not.

How to do this ?

I tried below code.. its executing as expected but its executing twice .

```
@echo on

call :sub "D:\temp\test*.zip"

if exist "D:\temp\Updates\%filename%" (set flag="true") else (set flag="false")

echo %flag%

:sub
set filename=%~nx1
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Place `goto :EOF` on the line above `:sub` but it's not going to execute twice.  What do you see on the console?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike many languages, batch has no concept of the end of a "procedure" - it simply continues execution line-by-line until it reaches the end-of-file. Consequently, you need to `goto :eof` after completing the mainline, otherwise execution will continue through the subroutine code. `:EOF` is a predefined label understood by `CMD` to mean `end of file`. The colon is **required**.